# Alternate between add and subtract on a range of numbers

Tags: python, list

How to get the sum of the series 1-2+3-4+5-6+7-8+9-10 in Python?

I know how to get the sum of numbers from 1 to a particular number by using while loop in this way:

```
i = 1
sum = 0
while i<= 10:
    sum = sum + i
    i = i + 1
print(sum)
```

Comment: if you dont want to waste energy you should think about the series a bit before writing any code. Hint: the series is (1-2)+(3-4)+(5-6)+ ...

Comment: But he just wants a 'coding' way of doing it. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: You are halfway there, keep doing your sum, but try mod 2 to determine if you should use + or - using a IF condition in your loop, then youre done.

Comment: @iWillGetBetter coding includes formulating the problem in a way that it can be solved by a program. Writing efficient and meaningful code should be part of the exercise.

Comment: Note: `sum` is a builtin function in python, you (and the answers) shouldn't use `sum` as a variable name.

Comment: Also note: you can use a `for` loop `for i in range(1, 11):` instead of `i = 0; while i <= 10: ... i = i + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Given you are trying to alternate the sign you can use the fact that `(-1)**n` also alternates the sign. But you want a negative when `n` is even you will need `(-1)**(n-1)`:

```
>>> list(n*(-1)**(n-1) for n in range(1, 11))
[1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6, 7, -8, 9, -10]
>>> sum(n*(-1)**(n-1) for n in range(1, 11))
-5
```

This can be turned into an explicit looping solution with:

```
t = 0
for n in range(1, 11):
    t += n*(-1)**(n-1)
print(t) # -5
```

Answer (score 2):

your code need a very small change:

```
i = 1
sum = 0
sign = 1
while i<= 10:
    sum = sum + sign * i
    sign = sign * -1
    i = i + 1
print(sum)
```

There are more pythonic ways to do what you requested - but they will require a little more knowledge..

Comment: Thank you so much definately the easiest one to understand yet so stressful for a beginner like me well today i realised its not as easy as i thought it is (python) guess thats what makes it special. Thanks anyway have a good day.

Comment: how do i find the sum of the series (1/2)+(2/3)+(3/4)+(4/5)+(5/6) in python the same way? tried this...i = 1
j = 2
while j <= 6:
    sum = i/j

    i = i + 1
    j = j + 1
print(sum)

Comment: In your original code replace the "sum = sum + i" with "sum = sum + i/(i+1)" and of course change the while to "while i <= 5"

Answer (score 2):

You should do like:

```
i = 1
my_sum = 0
while i<= 10:
    if i % 2:  # True, if i is divisible by 2
        my_sum -= i
    else:
        my_sum += i 
    i += 1  # same as i = i + 1
```

Some other alternative approaches:

```
>>> sum((i if i % 2  else -i) for i in range(1, 11))
-5
>>> sum(map(lambda x: x if x %2 else -x, range(1, 11)))
-5
```

Comment: Edited the signs of `i` and `x` to give then correct answer.

Comment: @AChampion : Thanks for the edit and other corrections. I totally missed that.

Answer (score 2):

It can also be seen as `sum of odd` minus `sum of even`

```
sum(range(1, 11, 2)) - sum(range(2, 11, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand this to a much easier, linear solution that works for any n series like this:

```
def sum_subtract(n):
    return n // 2 * -1 + n % 2 * n
```

Every pair of numbers (1 - 2) + (3 - 4) + etc. equals -1, so you just floor divide by 2 and multiply by -1. Next if there is an odd number at the end (n % 2), you add that.

Comment: how do i find the sum of the series (1/2)+(2/3)+(3/4)+(4/5)+(5/6) in python the same way? tried this..

Comment: @s.usk This isn't as trivial and doesn't have an easy non-iterative solution like the above. Using a different approach though, this should work: `sum(i / (i + 1) for i in range(6))` EDIT: this won't work for Python2, which does floor division for ints with `/`. Replacing `1` with `1.0` should do the trick.

Answer (score -6):

You can use a generator expression like

```
>>> sum(v if v%2 else -v for v in range(11))
-5
```

Here we check if the index is even or odd and add the number accordingly.

Another way can be using the `zip` builtin, But this works only for an even range.

```
>>> sum(x-y for x,y in zip(l[::2],l[1::2]))
-5
```

You can avoid slices and reduce the code size by using `iter`. `iter` creates an iterator that'll be exhausted whenever it has been called.

```
>>> i = iter(l)
>>> sum(x-y for x,y in zip(i,i))
-5
```